# Question about family permit for non EU spouse and son

Tags: immigration, eu, resident-permit, family, eu-spouses

I am a Portuguese citizen through descent. My son is also registered as a EU national. We stay in Goa as I am a computer teacher. I will be shifting to UK in December. I wish to travel with my son and wife. My wife though is from Goa, India. She is an Indian national. Can she get residency in UK as she has to look after my son when I work. Do I apply for family permit and take her with me ?? Or do I have to stay in UK for the initial right of residency and then apply after I'm a 'qualified' person...

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to stay in the UK before your wife can join you; you can travel to the UK together.  From https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility:

> Applying as a family member or extended family member
>
> The EEA citizen you’re joining must either:
>
> - be in the UK already
> - be travelling with you to the UK within 6 months of the date of your application
>
> If they’ve been in the UK for more than 3 months they must either:
>
> - be a ‘qualified person’ (working, looking for work, self-employed, studying or self-sufficient)
> - have a permanent right of residence

Note that the requirement to be a qualified person exists only if you've been in the UK for more than three months.

If you search online you will see that some people have had EEA family permits refused because the sponsor was not a qualified person.  These are either old stories, from when the UK was not properly honoring the EU directive, or they are incorrect refusals.  If you receive such a refusal, you should complain so it can be corrected.

Comment: Do I need to apply for 2 family permits or just one?

Comment: @Joyce why would you need 2?  You and your son are both EU nationals, so you don't need EEA family permits.  Your wife is Indian, so she needs one.

Comment: A website mentioned that I have to show some money in our joint account. To show that we won't be a social burden. Do you know the amount that has to be show on the bank slips? Also do I have to provide accommodation details

Comment: @Joyce for the EEA family permit, you do not need to show finances or accommodation. Those may be required for people applying for family reunion under the UK immigration rules, but the EEA FP is controlled by EU law, and the requirements are different.  That law only says that if you want to stay longer than 90 days, you need to be a qualified person, which you will be if you are working.

Comment: I'm going alone now as we have come across a financial hurdle. Do you have any idea about qualified person? I went to a agency here but there are charging £100 to even ask a question

Comment: @Joyce if you have a job, or are self employed, you are a qualified person.  There are other ways to qualify ("working, looking for work, self-employed, studying or self-sufficient").  If you have been in the UK for less than 90 days, you don't need to be "qualified," but after 90 days, you do.